# Is it possible to import input data from website to another?

Tags: javascript

I want to import input data from my website to another website form.
I want to know how to do that using JavaScript.
If it is possible please show an example.
For illustration: I have a login form in my website and a login form in my friend's website and i want my clients to use their account to login to my friend's website as i am helping him is it possible to do that without editing the man's source code or i have to edit it?
PS: I don't own the other website.
here is the the code of what i want

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

function open(){
var mywindow = window.open("myfriendwebsite.com", "_balnk");
mywindow.document.getElementById("id").value = email;
mywindow.document.getElementById("password").value = pass;
};
```

Comment: its not possible ..

Comment: What do you want to do really?! If you have access to the other website, you can receive the input data, if you change the `action` url of the input login form.

Comment: I have a login form in my website and a login form in my friend's website and i want my clients to use their account to login to my friend's website as i am helping him is it possible to do that without editing the man's source code or i have to edit it?

Comment: if it isn't possible by php can it be by JS or asp.net?

Comment: Google single sign on for cross site logins. But the point is that whether Javascript or server side, you need to tell the code to execute what you need to do, such as send curl (php) or ajax request to the other site,etc. Think about what you want to accomplish and then go on to think about solutions.